# When does the second derivative of a multivariate function depend on the order of derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In all my practice I have simply taken as given that

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$$

When does this not hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not hold in general when $f$ doesn't have continuous second partial derivatives at a point $(x_0,y_0)$. Take for example
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y-xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$,  then the second partial derivatives exist on $\mathbb R^2$ but we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=1$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)=-1.$$